# Doctrine : OneToMany relation with attributs

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

First, thank you for your time.

I'm developing a website with Symfony5, and I'm using Doctrine2 to create and manage the database. However, I've been struggling with a relation between two entities.

The database contains 2 important tables : Shard and Wheel.

These Wheels are use to draw motifs on the Shards, and a Wheel can be used to draw on multiple Shards. On the contrary, only one Wheel is used per Shard. This would be fairly easy with a OneToMany/ManyToOne relation, but the thing is that this relation needs to contain an attribut '*equal*' (a boolean which is true if the motifs were drawn by this exact Wheel, or false if it's really close, but not the exact one).

I went through the doctrine documentation chapter about relations, but I didn't find anything about OneToMany relations with attributs (I saw [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) but from what I understand, you can't add attributs).

After a while, I decided to do it 'manually', by creating an entity '*ShardWheel*', and so I did something along the line of this :

**Shard entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="shard")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ShardRepository")
 */
class Shard {
 ...
    /**
     * @var ShardWheel|null
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ShardWheel", mappedBy="shard")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $shardWheel;
 ...
```

**ShardWheel entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="shard_wheel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ShardWheelRepository")
 */
class ShardWheel {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="equal", type="boolean")
     */
    private $equal;

    /**
     * @var Wheel
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Wheel", inversedBy="draw")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $wheel;

    /**
     * @var Shard
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Shard", inversedBy="shardWheel")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $shard;
```

**Wheel entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="wheel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\WheelRepository")
 */
class Wheel {
 ...
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ShardWheel", mappedBy="wheel")
     * // This just serve as an indicator, the constructor initializes the ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $draw;
 ...
```

The thing is that it doesn't seem to work. I know it's not a common thing to do, so there are not a lot of questions/answers about this. I tried a lot of combinations, and I got lost. I may be dumb. Any suggestions ?

PS : Sorry if I did any spelling errors and/or weird sentences, it's pretty late and I'm really tired.

Edit : I made a real quick MCD of what I want : [MCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBqsV.jpg)

Comment: This approach should work. `oneToMany/ManyToOne` is essentially `ManyToMany` with more control, i.e. an Entity in between, i.e. you can add extra properties, like you did. Can you be more specific when you say `This doesn't seem to work...` What doesn't work exactly? Where in your code execution you run into a problem? Do you get any errors? Post them please... Data model seems fine (I didn't check for typos or grammar errors) except that I would maybe reconsider to make `Shard::$shardWheel` as `oneToMany` if it makes sense.

Comment: In this case, I want to ensure that `Shard` has only  one (or zero) relation with `Wheel`, that's why there is a _OneToOne_ relation between `Shard` and `ShardWheel`. Changing `Shard::$shardWheel` would force me to change `ShardWheel::$shard` to a _ManyToOne_ (or can I reverse a _OneToMany_ with a _OneToOne_ ? I doesn't make sense). The thing is that each `Shard` is linked to one or zero `ShardWheel`, but the same `Shard` can appear in multiple `ShardWheel::$shard` rows, isn't Doctrine supposed to prevent that ? Do I have to make the `ShardWheel::$shard` rows unique manually ?

Comment: the `@ORM\JoinColumn` on both `Shard::$shardWheel` and `Wheel::$draw` don't make much sense, since there should be no column. That aside, when you have a one-to-many between Shard and Wheel, the relation attributes go on the `many` side (and it should work). However, if you really want an extra table and entity ... the same Shard appearing in multiple ShardWheels should not be possible, however, maybe you forgot to update the schema, because there should be a unique constraint on shard_wheel.shard (maybe you can check?), however, adding it now won't work with the non-uniques. delete them first

Comment: the `@ORM\JoinColumn` are just visual aids, I doesn't seem to impact the database from what I've seen, but it gives me the information that these fields (or rather ArrayCollections) are allowed to be empty. I'm going to delete them just to be sure. I dropped the database, recreated it, reran the migrations, and it seems to work just fine (I checked,  the latest migration was applied, so I don't know how I fucked up...). I thought about putting _equal_ inside the `Shard`, but I wanted to use Doctrine constraints as much as possible to prevent me from screwing something up inside controllers.